# Buttonの状態に応じて、text,textColor,BackgroundColorを変えるには

Tags: android

以下のように、Color State Listを使うことでtextColorだけは実装できました。
同じように、textや、BackgroundColorも状態によって変化させる方法は無いでしょうか。

res/color/button_text_color.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000000" />
    <item android:color="#ffffff" />
</selector>
```

res/layout/exsample.xml

```
...
<Button
    android:textColor="@color/button_text_color" />
...
```

Answer (score 2):

ボタン状態によってtextを変更させる方法はちょっと分かりません。

背景色の場合は、文字色と同じように`selector`のxmlを作成し、`background`に設定します。

res/drawable/bg_button.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="false">
        <color android:color="#ff8888"/>
    </item>
    ・・・省略
</selector>
```

res/layout/example.xml

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button"/>
```

ただし、色だけを指定した場合、単にベタ塗りとなってしまい、ボタンっぽくないです。
ボタンっぽくした上で色を指定する場合、お好みの色や形で画像を用意するか、`shape`を利用すると綺麗に表示されると思います。

画像を指定する例（sdkのbtn_default.xmlなどを参考にするといいと思います）

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    ・・・省略
</selector>
```

`shape`で指定する例

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff9999"/>
            <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ff8888"/>
            <padding
                android:left="8dp"
                android:right="8dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    ・・・省略
</selector>
```

`API Level21`以降で色を変更する場合、上記のように指定すると`ripple`(波紋)が表示されなくなるので、
その場合は`<ripple>`を使用します。

画像を使う場合、`state_pressed="ture"`のときは`<ripple>`で波紋の色を指定し、その中で画像を指定します。

```
<item
    android:state_pressed="true">
    <ripple android:color="#ffcccc">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn" />
    </ripple>
</item>
```

`shape`で指定する場合は画像と同様に`<ripple>`で波紋の色を指定し、その中で`<shaple>`を定義します。

```
<item
    android:state_pressed="true">
    <ripple android:color="#ffcccc">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ff9999"/>
                <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="#ff8888"/>
                <padding
                    android:left="8dp"
                    android:right="8dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </ripple>
</item>
```

`API Level21`以降でボタンの色だけ変えたい場合は、テーマで指定する方法もあります。

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <!-- ボタン背景色 -->
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#88ff88</item>
    <!-- ボタンの場合は押されたときの色になります。ボタン以外でも使われます -->
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">#993333</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

初めまして。
backgroundの場合はちょっとやり方が変わります。

これをbackground属性に定義すれば反映されると思います。

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
<item android:state_selected="true" >  
    <color android:color="#ff0000" />  
</item>  
<item android:state_selected="false">  
    <color android:color="#00ff00" />  
</item>  
</selector>
```