# setEnabled(false)のボタンの透明度を変えたい。

Tags: android, java

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

このときのデフォルトの透明度が知りたいです。もしくはfalseのときの状態のときの透明度をなくしたいです。

**試したこと**

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(button.getAlpha())); // 結果は1でした
```

enabled falseのときは1の状態で透明ということになりますから、これは一体どうすればいいんでしょうか？

Comment: 「falseのときの状態のときの透明度をなくしたい」についてですが、[関連質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/8845/13972)がありました。回答ではなく質問の方にxmlで状態別のtextColorを指定(当然アルファ値も指定可)する方法が書いてあります。(リンク先を間違えていたのでコメントしなおしました。失礼。)

Answer (score 0):

**終わらせていただきます（質問者自身による投稿）**
setEnabledのfalseのときの**デフォルトカラーの透明度**を変えたかったのですが、あまりこだわらなくてもよいのかなと思えてきました。

xmlで状態別を指定する方法はネットで検索すればでてきますね。

質問の消し方がわからないのでとりあえずはこのままにしておきます。

失礼いたしました。